# UITextField scrollTextFieldToVisible Crash

Tags: ios, ios7

I often get a particular crash report for one of my iOS apps, and I haven't a clue what's causing it. I've included the stack trace below and I'm wondering if anyone can help.

The crash is occurring on iPad on iOS 7. I haven't been able to reproduce it myself, and it doesn't appear to link to anything in my code, but rather in UIKit (I don't see the `scrollTextFieldToVisible` method anywhere in my project.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a5ec626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x32909db1 -[UITextField scrollTextFieldToVisible] + 304
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2fac3f01 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2fa37d69 _CFXNotificationPost + 1720
4  Foundation                     0x30423cc5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
5  UIKit                          0x323f7a59 -[UIInputViewTransition postNotificationsForTransitionEnd] + 944
6  UIKit                          0x32794a95 __53-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]_block_invoke1364 + 336
7  UIKit                          0x3236b76d -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 284
8  UIKit                          0x3236b3b7 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 178
9  UIKit                          0x3236b2cf -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
10 QuartzCore                     0x31fb5e0b CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 234
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3aacbd3f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3aace6c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2facc641 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2facaf0d __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2fa35729 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2fa3550b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17 GraphicsServices               0x349716d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
18 UIKit                          0x32396871 UIApplicationMain + 1136
19 PilotPro                       0x000818bb main (main.m:17)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without a code telling something is not easy, my rough guess would be you are doing something to a UI element in another thread?

Comment: I would recommend using NSZombie to figure where exactly its crashing.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I see this exact trace (line-for-line) fairly often for one of my apps. It's mysterious. I'm unsure how to track it down.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, and the crash still occurs occasionally. :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to nil out an IBOUTLET reference to a UITextField in dealloc of one of your classes? Assuming your project is non-arc?

I experienced this issue too and and found out, with NSZombies enabled, that this was caused by a UITextField messaging respondsToSelector on it's delegate.

I don't know exactly what happens, but I assume the following:

1. Somewhere a viewController has been deallocated without releasing a reference to a UITextField
2. The UITextField is now leaking and has a dangling reference to its delegate (the viewController)
3. In another view a UITextField is tapped/becomes first responder
4. This invokes the keyboard and sends out a keyboard appear notification
5. The leaking text field is still observing keyboard notifications (**CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER**)
6. The leaking UITextField messages "scrollTextFieldToVisible" as a response to the notification
7. This method messages "respondsToSelector" on the UITextField delegate
8. This results in a crash since its delegate is no longer allocated

Comment: My project is using ARC. I still haven't found a solution, but I plan to drop support for iOS 7 soon in order to make this problem go away. :)